# Could not find Required file on "Npm Start"

Tags: reactjs, terminal

I'm creating a chat application using react and trying to run the app for the first time, but I'm getting the error messages shown in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ2Oa.png). The index.js file is located in the SRC file.

Comment: Hello vandriquez, a few notes: Please try to provide the output like the one from console as text instead of images, second we will probably need more information than that. What did you do? - What files do you have?

Answer (score 0):

First try to do npm install  by running the command :

```
npm install
```

after its done try npm start again.

Comment: Well, just to clarify you're not installing npm itself but the packages *required* in `package.json` using the `npm` command